# Visual Studio 2015 Crashing when opening old razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to install VS 2015 Enterprise edition on my computer but keep running into an issue.  Hunting through SO for the last 24 hours,  I've already tried the devenv.exe /ResetUserData & clearing the VS cache fixes, uninstalling enterprise edition and installing professional edition (which still failed for the same reason) and then reinstalling enterprise edition.  I've tried deleting the .vs folder before opening the solution, ensuring that the MVC versions in the /Views/ web.config matches the version of the sites web.config (MVC 5.2.3.0).

As of this morning, I've noticed that it only crashes when I try to open a razor view that wasn't created through Visual Studio 2015 (I was using VS 2012 previously, and I'm trying to work on this project in 2015 now that I have a license).  I can right-click in the solution explorer to create a brand new view and write anything I want in it with intellisense and save it, and open it back up without any issues.

I get the whole "An exception has occurred, this may be caused by an extension" message and then visual studio restarts if I try to open up a view that was already created through VS 2012.

I've tried looking inside of the log that it provides but I'm a newer developer so I can't really deduce anything from it..I'll attach it if anyone else can make anything of it.

MS VS Enterprise 2015 - Version 14.0.25029.00 Update 2 RC - .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055

I just cleared out the ActivityLog.XML and forced the error to get a fresh set of details - http://pastebin.com/j7RbGJFP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in this blog post - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/12/visual-studio-keeps-showing-suggested-extensions/.  It has to do with the extensions suggestion - it turns out if you have files not included in your project, you can't view them because of a bug introduced through the extensions suggestion.  If you turn that off and include the views in the project, VS won't crash and you'll have intellisense.